# To update the dataframe - what is difference between df.columns.get_loc vs df['colname']?

Tags: python, pandas

iloc supports only integers and not names. So the following code is valid:

```
for row in range(0, len(df)):
    df.iloc[row, df.columns.get_loc('ColName')] = 3
```

Following code is invalid because it uses column name rather than integer:

```
for row in range(0, len(df)):
    df.iloc[row, 'ColName'] = 3
```

To fix the above there are 3 options:

1. `df.iloc[row, df.columns.get_loc('ColName')] = 3`
2. `df['ColName'].iloc[row] = 3`
3. `df.iloc[row, colPositionInteger] = 3`

I would like to know the difference between points 2 and 3. For example - whether it is impacted by the view/copy concept.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a value with .iloc is not a problem. It can become a problem when you make a copy with an iloc slice.

Are you aware of .loc? That is used for slicing with labels. Perhaps this is just an example code but you can very easily do:

```
for row in df.index:
    df.loc[row, 'ColName'] = 3
```

which of course is equivalent to

```
df['ColName'] = 3
```

Comment: Please can you give me an example for "Setting a value with .iloc is not a problem. It can become a problem when you make a copy with an iloc slice." - is it the option 2 from my question?

Comment: AFAIK are .loc where you use index names or .iloc where you use integers pretty much the same. Imagine if you have a table with details for all country in the world and then you make a copy with .loc to select all countries in Asia and you save it as a new variable. In that case they are somewhat related still. You can add df.copy() to make an separate copy. That is different from looking at all countries in North and South America and changing the continent value to America (which some people learn in school). There is still only one dataframe in that case.